# Android Namespace lxml python

Tags: android, python, lxml

My code displays a xml for the android operating system.

I need to display

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

I tried

```
ET.Element("{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}name")
```

but it displays

```
<ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Can someone give me a snippet how to solve that?

Comment: Are you sure that the namespace prefixes actually matter here?  For most XML processing, they don't: dealing with QNames in content is pretty much the only place where that isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to, provide a namespace map (mapping prefixes to namespace uri) when creating the element, like this:

```
nsmap = {"android", "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}name"}
elem = ET.Element("{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}name", nsmap=nsmap)
```

Or register the prefix mapping globally, so that the "android" prefix will be used automatically when an element in that namespace is created:

```
ET.register_namespace("android", "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android")
```